# Find nodes with same relationships that initial node

Tags: neo4j

I have customers (id, name, type),  commerces (id, name, type)  and  relationships between them (idcustomer, idcommerce, quantity) that indicates that a customer has bought in a commerce and the quantity.

Well, I want to achieve nodes that have same relationships that the origin node, I mean, if customer 1  bought in commerce id=10 and id=11 I want to achive other customers who have bought in exact the same commerces (at least) that customer 1 in order to recommend the rest of commerces.

Now, I have next command but it doesn't work because it returns me all customers that have bought in one of the commerce where customer 1 bought but not in all of them.

```
START m=node:id(id="1") MATCH  (m)-[:BUY]->(commerces)<-[:BUY]-(customers)  RETURN customers;
```

Example

```
Customer 1   bought  commerce  10, 11
Customer 2   bought  commerce  10, 3
Customer 3   bought  commerce  10, 11, 4
Customer 4   bought  commerce  5, 8, 10
```

The return that I want is Customer 3 in order to recommend commerce 4.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution,

The first query gets all of the products the start node m buys, that is the collect(commerce) of the first "WITH" clause;

The second query gets all products each customer shares with the m, that is the customerCommerces of the second "With" clause;

Then the "Where" clause eliminates those customers who share only a subset of the products bought by the m, therefore returns the customers who share all of the products with the m.

```
START m=node:id(id="1")
Match (m)-[:BUY]->(commerce)
With collect(commerce) as mCos
START m=node:id(id="1")
Match (m)-[:BUY]->(commerce)<-[:BUY]-(customer)
with mCos, customer, collect(commerce) as customerCommerces
Where length(mCos) = length(customerCommerces)
Return customer
```